# How to use custom directive on a custom component's host element

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I have a custom directive which should listen to `ngModelChange` of a custom component and add or remove items in an array.

Here's the directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[selectedItems]'
})

export class SelectedItemsDirective {
  @Input('ngModel') ngModel: boolean;
  @Input() mainNgModel: boolean;
  @Input() items: any[] = [];
  @Input() item: any;
  @Input() itemKey: string;
  @Output() itemsChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  @HostListener('ngModelChange')
  modelChange() {

    const i: number = this.items.indexOf(this.item[this.itemKey]);

    if (i === -1 && this.ngModel) {
      this.items.push();
    }
    else {
      this.items.splice(i, 1);
    }

    this.itemsChange.emit(this.items);
  }
}
```

And then it'll be used like this:

```
<checkbox [(ngModel)]="event.isChecked" [(selectedItems)]="selectedEvents" [items]="events" [item]="event"></checkbox>
```

But this doesn't work because:

```
Can't bind to 'selectedItems' since it isn't a known property of 'checkbox'.
```

And I'm guessing that the same will occur for the directive's input properties as well.

I can't seem to google my way to a solution that's remotely close to what I'm trying to achieve. I've declared and exported the directive in the `SharedModule` which I've then imported into the checkbox's module.

What more do I have to do in order for this to work?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you forgot to apply `directives` to your `@Component()`.

 

 
**Example:**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'YourApp',
    templateUrl: 'YourTemplateUrlHere',
    directives: [SelectedItemsDirective] 
})
```

And one more suggestion don't write all the code, just start by binding the directive then add very basic `console.log()` stuff then add all these two way bindings one at a time.

Spent three hours debugging just for a spelling mistake in directive. Yay experience :)